# How did the Tanners' mom die?

Tags: character, full-house

On the TV show 'Full House', Danny Tanner was left to raise three daughters by himself.

My Question: How did the Tanners' mom die?

Comment: I saw that [horror movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m4-lSllrXk)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you read the [transcript for Full House Episode 40](http://www.full-house.org/episodes/episodes_script_040.php) they mention that Pam Tanner was killed in a car accident. The wiki states she was hit by a drunk driver, but I could not find a reference to that specific information.